# How to download amazon-s3 images using scrapy

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy

I'm trying to download images using scrapy but the problem is, I couldn't found path to get that image url. They are using s3 for their images. That's why if i type view(response) i can see blank gallery. So how can I get path or images link? Here is the website link. Please have a look [site](https://www.pickaboo.com/a4tech-fb35-multimode-bluetooth-2-4g-mouse.html)

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Please post the code relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can get the main image by using this xpath: `response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]').extract_first()`
- If you want all images: the links of the images are present in the html, but a bit hidden in a json-structure. The following code loads the json-structure into a python dictionary and gathers the image links:

```
import json
image_json = response.xpath('//*[@type="text/x-magento-init"][contains(text(), "mage/gallery/gallery")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
image_dict = json.loads(image_json)
images_data = image_dict['[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]']['mage/gallery/gallery']['data']
image_urls = [image_data['img'] for image_data in images_data]
```